# what does const TAB = ^I in pascal?

Tags: java, groovy, pascal, jvm-languages

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/tutor1.txt). Under the heading **The Cradle**, you can see the code:

```
const TAB = ^I;
```

well this is a pascal code, actually I'm trying to re-implement those pascal code to Java or groovy(so that I can build a kind of compiler using Java or groovy). But what does the above coding statement meant in pascal?

How I can represent it in Java or Groovy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^I` is simply a short-hand for `Control+I`, which is a representation of ASCII tab character (code 9). On old terminals, pressing (and holding) the control key while pressing a character produced the characters from the ASCII control character range (e.g., Ctrl+A = ASCII 1, ..., Ctrl+M = ASCII 13 = Newline, etc.)

In Groovy, you should probably use `final char Tab = '\t'`

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy 1.8.4, I settled on  simply:

```
def Tab = '\t'
```

as this kept giving errors:

```
final char Tab = '\t'
```